# How to convert a Option[String] to Option[Int]?

Tags: json, scala

I am reading and parsing a json file. One of the field of the json file is Nullable. It either returns a string of digits or Null. I need to convert the string to int.  I am able to convert from String to Option[Int] by the below code, but not able to convert from Option[String] to Option[Int]

```
 def toInt(userId: String):Option[Int] = {
  try {
    Some(userId.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e:Exception => None
  }
}

val user = toInt("abc")
```

What changes do I need to do?

Comment: What about Try(userId.toInt).toOption

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
import util.Try

def toInt(o: Option[String]): Option[Int] =
  o.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
```

Examples:

```
scala> toInt(None)
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> toInt(Some("42"))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(42)

scala> toInt(Some("abc"))
res2: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Sorry, am a Scala newbie. When I run using your method, then it is working fine. But why does the following call is failing: 
`scala> None.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
<console>:10: error: value toInt is not a member of Nothing
              None.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)`

Comment: Following worked for me: `Try(o.getOrElse("").toInt).toOption`   I am on Scala version 2.11

Answer (score 6):

```
Option(userId).map(_.toInt)
```

Use `Option` instead of `Some`. Than use `map` to convert it to `Int`

Answer (score 3):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]):

Which combined to a `flatMap` provides a safe way to cast from `Option[String]` to `Option[Int]`:

```
Option("1").flatMap(_.toIntOption)            // Option[Int] = Some(1)
(None: Option[String]).flatMap(_.toIntOption) // Option[Int] = None
Option("abc").flatMap(_.toIntOption)          // Option[Int] = None
Option(null: String).flatMap(_.toIntOption)   // Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `map` the `Option` to do something with possible contained value. In the context of your code, I would use `flatMap`, since the current method returns `Option`, so we must flatten what would be a nested `Option`.

```
def toInt(userIdOpt: Option[String]): Option[Int] = userIdOpt flatMap { userId =>
  try {
    Some(userId.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e:Exception => None
  }
}

scala> val u = Option("2")
u: Option[String] = Some(2)

scala> toInt(u)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> toInt(Some("a"))
res4: Option[Int] = None
```

We can shorten this using `Try`.

```
import scala.util.Try

def toInt(userIdOpt: Option[String]): Option[Int] =
    userIdOpt.flatMap(a => Try(a.toInt).toOption)
```

`Try(a.toInt)` returns a `Try[Int]`, where a successful conversion will be a `Success[Int]`, and a failed conversion (not an integer) would be a `Failure[Throwable]`. `Try` has a very convenient method called `toOption` which will convert `Success(a)` to `Some(a)`, and `Failure` to `None`, which is exactly what we want.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @Chris Martin and @Michael Zajac works fine:

```
import util.Try

def toInt(o: Option[String]): Option[Int] =
  o.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
```

**BUT**

If the input data is incorrect often then It will increase the producing of `NumberFormatException` by `Try` and that is bad for a garbage collector. It needs to utilize more stack traces after operations. 
It means we should try to avoid `scala.util.Try` here.

Here is not a short but more performant solution in case that input data is often incorrect:

```
def toInt(s: Option[String]): Option[Int] = s match {
  case None => None
  case Some(v) if v.isEmpty  => None
  case Some(v) => if (v.forall(_.isDigit) || (v.startsWith("-") && v.drop(1).forall(_.isDigit)))
    Some(v.toInt)
  else
    None
}
```

Test:

```
 scala>   toInt(None)
    res0: Option[Int] = None
 scala>   toInt(Some(""))
    res1: Option[Int] = None
 scala>   toInt(Some("42"))
    res2: Option[Int] = Some(42)
 scala>   toInt(Some("-42"))
    res3: Option[Int] = Some(-42)
 scala>   toInt(Some("abc"))
    res4: Option[Int] = None
```

Summary: Never use exceptions for control flow!